# How to get data from mysql database to a JSP page?

Tags: mysql, jsp

I am new this JSP world..
My question is
I want to get data from a mysql database aand need to print that using a JSP page...How can I do this..How to write the code in the servlet and in the JSP file...Please help me people..
The answers given to similar titles are little bit tough though...

Thank You guyz a lot
Regards
KSNT

Comment: Per my answer, spend some time on Google before asking and you'll get a little further with SO.

Comment: If you are new to JSP world, then you should go for something which is not deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8764366/870122

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty basic JSP and Java and I think you should spend more time on Google and post some examples first before asking a basic question like this. Here is a place to start:

http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysqldatabase.shtml

Please note, that is NOT the best way to work with JSP and database code. You should not embed your java code in JSP like that. The database work is best done in classes that you reference from your JSP, but I just pasted that link to get you started. Google is your friend.

Comment: Yes that was a very simple question..Btw thanks a lot for the comments made by  davidethell,  perissf..I did it correctly..thank u people a lot :)