# JSF tags not rendering - FacesServlet not working maybe?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I am just getting started with JSF 2.0 and I'm stuck on a problem at the very beginning. JSF tags are not parsed.

Below are some details. Hope someone can help because none of the related SO questions have been able to solve my problem.

**hello.jsp**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>

    </h:head>

    <h:body>
    <f:view>
        asd
        <h:inputText value="asd" label="UserName"></h:inputText>
    </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**What I see when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/JSFDeneme/pages/hello.jsp`**

Only the plaintext `asd`

**View source of `http://localhost:8080/JSFDeneme/pages/hello.jsp`**

Exactly the same as the contents of `hello.jsp`

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>    
    </h:head>    
    <h:body>
    <f:view>asd
        <h:inputText value="asd" label="UserName"></h:inputText>
        </f:view>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

**web.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" 
         version="3.0">
  <display-name>JSFDeneme</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>hello.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/pages/*</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    This parameter tells MyFaces if javascript code should be allowed in
    the rendered HTML output.
    If javascript is allowed, command_link anchors will have javascript code
    that submits the corresponding form.
    If javascript is not allowed, the state saving info and nested parameters
    will be added as url parameters.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ALLOW_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, rendered HTML code will be formatted, so that it is 'human-readable'
    i.e. additional line separators and whitespace will be written, that do not
    influence the HTML code.
    Default is 'true'</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.PRETTY_HTML</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.DETECT_JAVASCRIPT</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <description>
    If true, a javascript function will be rendered that is able to restore the
    former vertical scroll on every request. Convenient feature if you have pages
    with long lists and you do not want the browser page to always jump to the top
    if you trigger a link or button action that stays on the same page.
    Default is 'false'
</description>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.AUTO_SCROLL</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
</faces-config>
```

**What I have in `WEB-INF/lib`**

- JSF 2.0 (Apache Myfaces JSF Core-2.0 API 2.0.2) - Eclipse downloaded that
- jstl-api-1.2.jar
- jstl-impl-1.2.jar
- primefaces-3.0 jars

**What Tomcat prints to console when I restart the server and navigate to the page**

There seems nothing odd and no mention of `FacesServlet`?

```
06.Oca.2012 22:26:55 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\glassfish3\jdk\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86_64;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\apache-ant-1.8.2\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;.
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AjaxDenemeleri' did not find a matching property.
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:RPGW_RestAPI' did not find a matching property.
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JSFDeneme' did not find a matching property.
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 680 ms
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.22
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  sample.hello.resources
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class sample.hello.resources.HelloResource
  class sample.hello.resources.ContactsResource
06.Oca.2012 22:26:56 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
06.Oca.2012 22:26:57 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.10 11/02/2011 03:53 PM'
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "org.apache.myfaces.webapp.StartupServletContextListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_CLEAR_JAVASCRIPT_FOR_BUTTON' found, using default value false
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_HIDDEN_FIELDS_FOR_LINK_PARAMS' found, using default value false
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.SAVE_FORM_SUBMIT_LINK_IE' found, using default value false
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.READONLY_AS_DISABLED_FOR_SELECTS' found, using default value true
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_VIEWSTATE_ID' found, using default value true
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.STRICT_XHTML_LINKS' found, using default value true
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.RENDER_FORM_SUBMIT_SCRIPT_INLINE' found, using default value false
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getLongInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.CONFIG_REFRESH_PERIOD' found, using default value 2
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VIEWSTATE_JAVASCRIPT' found, using default value false
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getStringInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS' found, using default value auto
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.REFRESH_TRANSIENT_BUILD_ON_PSS_PRESERVE_STATE' found, using default value false
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.VALIDATE_XML' found, using default value false
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig getBooleanInitParameter
INFO: No context init parameter 'org.apache.myfaces.WRAP_SCRIPT_CONTENT_WITH_XML_COMMENT_TAG' found, using default value true
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.config.MyfacesConfig createAndInitializeMyFacesConfig
INFO: Tomahawk jar not available. Autoscrolling, DetectJavascript, AddResourceClass and CheckExtensionsFilter are disabled now.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator feedStandardConfig
INFO: Reading standard config META-INF/standard-faces-config.xml
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator addClassloaderConfigurations
INFO: Reading config : jar:file:/D:/documents/code/java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/JSFDeneme/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.0.jar!/META-INF/faces-config.xml
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator getWebAppConfig
INFO: Reading config /WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-api in version : 2.0.2 from path : file:/D:/documents/code/java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/JSFDeneme/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-api-2.0.2.jar
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: Starting up MyFaces-package : myfaces-impl in version : 2.0.2 from path : file:/D:/documents/code/java/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/JSFDeneme/WEB-INF/lib/myfaces-impl-2.0.2.jar
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk12 not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox12 not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tomahawk-sandbox15 not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : myfaces-orchestra-core not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : myfaces-orchestra-core12 not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : trinidad-api not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : trinidad-impl not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : tobago not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : commons-el not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator startLib
INFO: MyFaces-package : jsp-api not found.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.util.ExternalSpecifications isBeanValidationAvailable
INFO: MyFaces Bean Validation support disabled
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultAnnotationProvider webClasses
WARNING: AnnotationConfigurator does not found classes for annotations in /WEB-INF/classes/ . This could happen because maven jetty plugin is used (goal jetty:run). Try configure org.apache.myfaces.annotation.SCAN_PACKAGES init parameter or use jetty:run-exploded instead.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.application.ApplicationImpl getProjectStage
INFO: Couldn't discover the current project stage, using Production
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.FacesConfigurator handleSerialFactory
INFO: Serialization provider : class org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.util.serial.DefaultSerialFactory
06.Oca.2012 22:27:00 org.apache.myfaces.config.annotation.DefaultLifecycleProviderFactory getLifecycleProvider
INFO: Using LifecycleProvider java.lang.String
06.Oca.2012 22:27:01 org.apache.myfaces.webapp.AbstractFacesInitializer initFaces
INFO: ServletContext 'D:\documents\code\java\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\JSFDeneme\' initialized.
06.Oca.2012 22:27:01 org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener processEvent
INFO: Running on PrimeFaces 3.0
06.Oca.2012 22:27:01 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
06.Oca.2012 22:27:01 org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
06.Oca.2012 22:27:01 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4958 ms
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **hello.jsp**

This is not the right extension.

Since JSF 2.0, [JSP is deprecated and replaced by Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html). Facelets is a XML based view technology and supposed to be written in `.xhtml` files. However, you seem to already have used valid Facelets syntax in your JSP file. All you need to do is to just rename `hello.jsp` to `hello.xhtml`.

I also recommend to replace all URL patterns by a single URL pattern `*.xhtml`.

```html
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

so that you can open it by http://localhost:8080/JSFDeneme/hello.xhtml without fiddling with virtual URLs.

I'm not sure what books/tutorials you've read which made you to use the JSP extension. Perhaps you were reading a mix of JSF 1.x and JSF 2.x targeted tutorials. You need to make sure that you're reading JSF 2.x specific tutorials. At the bottom of [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) you can find several JSF 2.x tutorial links.

Comment: I renamed `hello.jsp` to `hello.xhtml` but then when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/JSFDeneme/pages/hello.xhtml`, I get the `Oops! This link appears to be broken.` page? Where should I navigate to view the page?

Comment: If you have replaced the URL pattern as well, you need to remove `/pages` from the URL. See also the example URL in my answer.

Comment: Works like a charm BalusC! Thanks a lot. 2 more questions, what `DOCTYPE` would you suggest? Or would you even suggest using one? And secondly, do I have to use the `.xhtml` extension? Can I use something else like `.do` or something arbitrary? Because when the file extension is `.xhtml` and I add another `url-mapping`, such as `.jsf`, it doesn't work.

Comment: Oh btw yeah I started by reading your tutorial on your blog, but then switched up to others and got it all mixed up...

Comment: You can use a different mapping, but you should not change the source file extension. It MUST be `.xhtml`. Otherwise you need to change the `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` context param. If you add a `*.jsf` mapping, then you should only change the URL extension. But the enduser would still be able to obtain the raw XHTML source code when using `.xhtml` in URL whenever it's not been mapped on `*.xhtml`. Hence my suggestion. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/5676142, http://stackoverflow.com/a/3512494. As to the doctype, read http://stackoverflow.com/q/2935759.

Comment: Learned a lot from your posts. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that, as you are invoking a `.jsp` URL you are rendering the page via the good old JSP servlet (you have the `/pages/*` URL mapped to the Faces servlet, but JSP extension mapping might be taking precedence).

Can you try renaming your page to a `.jsf` and invoking that?

Comment: Unfortunately, renaming to `.jsf` doesn't work neither, nor did `.xhtml`

Comment: Renaming to `.jsf` will indeed not work in any way. The default Facelets suffix is `.xhtml`.

Comment: Renamed the file extension to `.jsf` and changed the url-mappings accordingly. I navigated to the page and Eclipse's console gone mad! Threw exceptions in an infinite loop until I had to force and close it :)

Answer (score -3):

try to put following code in your web.xml

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee

    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"

    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

<display-name>jsfexample</display-name>

<servlet>

    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>faces</servlet-name>

    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>

</servlet-mapping>
```